# Database(MySQL) Error

Tags: mysql

I am trying to insert two records to my database at the same time. One with the primary key and the other with the foreign key. However, I get the following error when I try implementing this:

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails ....(database details).
```

I have used this query to create the foreign key:

```
ALTER TABLE `notes` ADD CONSTRAINT `notes_author_fk`
    FOREIGN KEY (`authorid`) REFERENCES `audiofeed`.`author`(`authorid`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

The error statement points at:

```
$query1 = "INSERT INTO notes(notename,categoryname,file,authorname)";
$query1 .= "VALUES ('$Trackname','$category','$name','$author')";
```

Comment: You haven't actually posted the statements that are producing the error.

Comment: If your error occurs during an insert / update / delete, then it means the FK is already in force and what you are proposing with the data change would violate the rule. The FK.

Comment: If an error occurs when you try the `ALTER TABLE`, it means your data is not ready for the rule you are trying to impose

Comment: @Drew i think the error occurs when i insert the data into the DB. Any advice on how i can solve this? I am very new to PHP

Comment: In that case it means new insert for `notes.authorid` is not kosher for what exists in `audiofeed.author.authorid` ...

Comment: I will save you the suspense. It is your AUTO_INCREMENT. The `LAST_INSERT_ID()` issue. Of course we know nothing about your schema. May I direct your attention to my [Share your World with Us](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38899464). It gets a little old after a while :p  <---- smile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the error does in fact occur during the `insert` statement that you posted, I notice that you are not inserting any value for the `authorid` column, which is the column that has a foreign key defined.

Normally, this should be ok, as it should simply insert `NULL`, and that would not violate the foreign key constraint.

However, if the `authorid` column in the `notes` table has a default value specification, it may be trying to insert an invalid default value that cannot be found in the `author` table, thus giving you the error.

You may want to verify how the `authorid` column is defined, and adjust it as necessary.

Or, make sure you set an appropriate value for `authorid` in your `insert` statement.

Comment: dont know why you delete your answer on my question. After the edit was correct.

Comment: @Juan: ha. yes, I basically had the answer, but I had to go eat, and didn't have time to think it through, so I preferred to delete it and let others answer.